# NSLocale Country Code and Name is Null

Tags: ios, xcode6, nslocale

I am using the below code for Code and Country name but it returns null.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *country = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
NSLog(@"Language : %@ Lang2 : %@",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0],[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Locale:%@ Code:%@ Name%@:", locale, countryCode, country);

developmentRegion = English;
        hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
        knownRegions = (
            en,
            Base,
            fr,
            de,
            nl,
            ja,
            es,
            tr,
            it,
            pl,
            pt,
        );
```

Logs : Locale:<__NSCFLocale: 0x7fbef943f810> Code:(null) Name(null)

Language : nl Lang2 : nl

[image]

Tested both on device and simulator.i don't know whats going on here.It should work fine.Please let me know if you guys have any idea.i am using xcode 6.4.

[image]

Comment: It works for me while using XCode 6.4, I think you need to check your `Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Region Formats` and set accordingly. It should work. Cheers.

Comment: i double checked.Everything is set accordingly :(

Comment: What is your Region set in the Simulator/Device Settings -> Region Formats  ?

Comment: Settings for both Device and Simulator.See my edit.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15202534/1865424

Comment: Its working for me as well- Xcode 6.4 (6E35b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the bugger.

I tested the above code in another test project and was working fine but not in my current project.
So i used the developer tool FileMerge and compared the two and found a difference in the below line.(xcshareddata->xcschemes->****.xcscheme).

[image]

I don't know how the language = "nl" got there may be due to a bad merge but rolling back and re-merge didn't work either.

Manually removing the line solved my Ghostly Problem :)